# IAM Policy to determine S3 Bucket access based on user tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a policy for all members of a group that will grant the user's access to particular S3 buckets based on a Tag value set on the user's account.

For example, my user has tag `environment=staging`, and I want to use this value to access buckets in s3 with the name `staging` -- for example: `my-${environment}-bucket`.

Here's what my policy looks like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-${aws:PrincipalTag/environment}-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-${aws:PrincipalTag/environment}-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently this isn't working. I must be missing something.

EDIT:

I'm using the IAM Policy Simulator tool (https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/) to test this user & policy. Screenshot below.

[image: Testing my Policy]

Comment: How isn't it working? What tests are you doing?

Comment: @jarmod I'm using the IAM Policy Simulator tool. I've updated my question to include a screenshot of the denial from the simulator tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to achieve the desired behavior. Here's a minimal reproducible example:

1. I created a user "*foobar*" with no permissions. I gave this user a tag `environment` with the value `test`. I gave this user the following inline policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*${aws:PrincipalTag/environment}*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. I created two buckets, one called `mydevbucket` and another called `mytestbucket`. I added one file to the `mytestbucket`, "*foo.txt*".
3. I logged in the AWS account as the "*foobar*" user, and tried to navigate to the two buckets: `https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/mytestbucket?region=eu-west-2&tab=objects` for the test bucket, `https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/mydevbucket?region=eu-west-2&tab=objects` for the dev bucket.

   As expected, I can only see the test bucket (because the `environment` tag has a the value `test`):

[image]

whereas in the dev bucket:

[image]

Comment: Hey @Paolo . Does your "foobar" user have management console access only? In my case, it's programmatic access only.

Comment: @Sixers17 console access, but that's irrelevant. I've demonstrated that you can use user tags to determine access to specific S3 buckets.

Comment: gotcha. One note I should mention about my test case FWIW: My user is associated to a group, and the policy in question is on the group. Does this matter?

Comment: @sixers17 no, that shouldn't matter. It will work that way as well. Whether it's inline or assigned to a group, a policy is a policy.

Comment: Ok, so it turns out that my policy WORKS if I run it from the CLI, but it's not working from the Policy Simulator Web tool. Weird. If anyone can explain that one I'd love to know.

Comment: @sixers17 I don't know if you'll be able to simulate it using the policy simulator tool, because for the simulation you would have to run the tool as a user with the certain tag; is that something you can configure on the simulator? Regardless, does it really matter?